# How do we promote specific databases (or tag areas) here?

Tags: discussion, tagging, site-promotion

I see a TON of questions and answers for SQLServer, Oracle, MySQL, and even Postgres. I do not see a lot of traffic on DB2. I'm sure some of that has to do with demographics and cost and what not. And maybe this is subjective, but I would love to see more DB2 action here on dba.stackexchange.com. Reason being that I've not seen much success on IBM specific forums. I've gotten more success with questions and answers on the stack exchanges sites (mostly dba.stackexchange.com and stackoverflow.com). I love the community. People respond honestly. Reputation and bounties help promote answers.

But how do we promote an area (such as DB2) to even get questions and answers in the first place? How do we get more DB2 users to use dba.stackexchange.com?

Thoughts?

Comment: How do we get more users? We get more content. How do we get more content? People ask questions. I will say that Jeopardy questions are ok (if you have an answer, build a question for it) and I wouldn't be against using a blog post to spur that, but if you wanted to seed some content here in that fashion (which I think is a bad idea ~ so much better to have organic content) then you absolutely must provide attribution back to the blog or post, and preferably give notice (you always should anyways) that you've done so to the OP, where possible.

Comment: I agree with the organic part. I don't really want to "seed" the site with false questions. I'm trying to look for ways to get more DB2 users/admins to visit the site organically.

Comment: That just generally takes awareness. Start emailing DB2 bloggers with an impassioned plea (if there are any)

Comment: I [asked a related question](http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/q/236/1396) back in May and there has only been gradual progress since then.

Comment: Good point. Am engaging those I know of to try to build up the DB2 user base on DBA SE.